# How to use ViewModelWidget in the onPressed callback of a button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-stacked

I am trying to use the `ViewModelWidget` class from the [stacked](https://pub.dev/packages/stacked) package. I am able to show the `TextWidget` which extends `ViewModelWidget` in the body of the page, but cannot show it in the bottom sheet because I am showing the bottom sheet from the `onPressed` function and that function does not have access to the view model.

Here is the code:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyView(),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class MyViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
  String title = 'Hello';

  void updateTitle() {
    title = 'Bye';
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```dart
class MyView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder<MyViewModel>.reactive(
      viewModelBuilder: () => MyViewModel(),
      builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('My View'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const TextWidget(),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return const SizedBox(child: Center(child: TextWidget(),), height: 200,);
                  },
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Show Modal'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextWidget extends ViewModelWidget<MyViewModel> {
  const TextWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, MyViewModel viewModel) {
    return Text(viewModel.title);
  }
}
```

And here's the error that happens when I try to open the bottom sheet:

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: hi, instead of calling TextWidget() as a viewmodel widget, you can pass the value from textwidget, and use as a normal widget.

for ex =>  TextWidget(model.title) and showthat inside the widget.

Comment: class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  TextWidget(this.title);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(title),
    );
  }
}

Comment: why updateTitle is never called ? shouln't be  onModelReady: (viewModel) => viewModel.updateTitle(), what about BaseViewModel  ? it should extends ChangeNotifier

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it

> The .nonReactive constructor is best used for providing your ViewModel
> to multiple child widgets that will make use of it. It was created to
> make it easier to build and provide the same ViewModel to multiple
> UI's. It was born out of the Responsive UI architecture where we would
> have to provide the same ViewModel to all the different responsive
> layouts.

As a result you should give a try to return `ViewModelBuilder<HomeViewModel>.nonReactive(`

Check the doc #Non Reactive : https://pub.dev/packages/stacked